# java: lombok: @Slf4j: log cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I am using openjdk11 and using **lombok** library. My @Slf4j **works fine in java path** (src/main/java) but gets error in test path(src/test/java). The error is " can not find symbol". May I get any insight on why is happening and how to fix?

I am using spring boot and unit tests are running with MockitoJUnitRunner. So the test classes are annotated as

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@Slf4j
public class ErrorPathUnitTest { 
}
```

Gradle version: 5.5
LOMBOK_VERSION:1.18.6

Comment: what is your gradle version ?

Comment: gradle version: 5.5

Comment: I'm not sure, i have no problem with those versions

Comment: what does your build.gradle look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could resolve this following the instruction here:  https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following gradle dependencies:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testCompile 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have **compileOnly** for lombok dependency in build.gradle